# How to prove this result on limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{({a+x^m})^{\frac{1}{n}}-({a-x^m})^{\frac{1}{n}}}{x^m}=\frac{2}{n}a^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$$

I have tried it using [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), but I don't get any way out of that.

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting $y=\frac {x^m}a,$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{({a+x^m})^{\frac{1}{n}}-({a-x^m})^{\frac{1}{n}}}{x^m} $$

$$= a^{\frac1n}\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{(1+y)^{\frac{1}{n}}-(1-y)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{ay} $$

$$= a^{\frac1n-1}\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{1+\frac yn+O(y^2))-(1-\frac yn+O(y^2)}y \text{ (using Binomial Expansion)}$$

$$=  a^{\frac1n-1} \lim_{y \to 0}\frac {\frac {2y}n+O(y^2)}y$$

$$=\frac{2 a^{\frac1n-1}}n \text{ as }y\ne0 \text{ as }y\to0$$

Comment: @ManojPandey, my pleasure

Answer (score 6):

Let $t=x^m$. Now L'Hospital's Rule will work very nicely. (It works with the original form too, but looks messier.)

Note that the derivative of $(a-t)^{1/n}$ is $-\frac{1}{n}(a-t)^{1-1/n}$.

Comment: Nicolas: I will definitely try using this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need to use L'Hospital's Rule at all.Its a simple consequence of mean value theorem.

By mean value theorem applied to $(a+y)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ we have

$\displaystyle\frac{({a+x^m})^{\frac{1}{n}}-({a-x^m})^{\frac{1}{n}}}{x^m}=2\frac{1}{n}(a+\epsilon)^{(1/n-1)}$, for some $\epsilon \in (-x^m,x^m)$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{({a+x^m})^{\frac{1}{n}}-({a-x^m})^{\frac{1}{n}}}{x^m}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{n}(a+\epsilon)^{(1/n-1)}$, for some $\epsilon \in (-x^m,x^m)$

Now by squeeze theorem we have ,

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{n}(a+\epsilon)^{(1/n-1)}=\frac{2}{n}(a)^{(1/n-1)}$ as $-x^{m}<\epsilon <x^m$

Comment: +1 Very nice, but I can't see how you use the squeeze theorem...What happens, imho, is that $\;\epsilon\to 0\;$ as $\,x\to 0\;$ , for $\,\epsilon\in (-x^m,x^m)\;$ . The last theorem is then straightforward,

Comment: thanks @DonAntonio what I meant is $\lim_{x\to 0}-x^m\le\lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon_x \le \lim_{x\to 0}x^m\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon_x=0$